# AEM - vault -package filter.xml query

Tags: maven, filter, build, package, aem

In my apps package filter.xml i have give as below:

```
<filter root="/apps/site">
    <include pattern="/apps/site/components"/>
    <include pattern="/apps/site/config"/>
    <include pattern="/apps/site/config(.*)?"/>
    <include pattern="/apps/site/install"/>
    <include pattern="/apps/site/pages"/>
    <include pattern="/apps/site/templates"/>    
</filter>
```

With the above code, when I am deploying my package,
any new folders/files created are getting updated in crxde
any existing html file changes are getting updated in crxde
but changes to component dialog.xml are not getting updated in crxde (to explain, I make changes directly in one of the component dialog in crxde and then i deploy my package. The changes I did are not getting udpated from my codebase is the problem)

So then I add the below pattern as well to the filter.xml and it works.

```
<include pattern="/apps/site/components(/.*)"/>
```

Can someone help me if we need to include both the below patterns in filter if this need to work or do we have an alternative approach?

```
<include pattern="/apps/site/components"/>
<include pattern="/apps/site/components(/.*)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you are observing is due to backward compatibility. When there was no merge mode yet then the behaviour was like this:
Install nodes matching filters using replace mode, everything else using merge mode (add new content only).

So for the filter like this:

```
<filter root="/apps/site">
     <include pattern="/apps/site/components"/>
</filter>
```

Everything from the package below `/apps/site/components` is installed using merge mode because there is no wildcard at the end.

If you change the filter to:

```
<filter root="/apps/site">
      <include pattern="/apps/site/components"/>
      <include pattern="/apps/site/components(/.*)"/>
</filter>
```

Then it match also nodes below, so package installer is using replace mode.

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple you can have `components`, `install`, `config` etc as filter roots, i.e.

```
<filter root="/apps/site/components">
<filter root="/apps/site/config">
<filter root="/apps/site/install">
```

and so on.

That way the tree starting with `/apps/site/components` is replaced every time you install the package and there's no need for `include` statements.

Update:
The `include` and `exclude` patterns are a good practice when your package will install stuff in parts of the tree that don't fully own; in your case, if there's another package that also installs stuff in `/apps/site`.